# QT QGraphicsScene auto resize to orginal Image size

Tags: c++, qt

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene();
view = new QGraphicsView(this);
scene->addPixmap(QPixmap( "xyz.jpeg" ));
scene->setSceneRect(0,0,325,302);
//scene->setSceneRect(scene->itemsBoundingRect());
view->setScene( scene );
view->show();
```

I have this code in Mainwindow constructor. Image is loading but. I must scroll to see all image (I can only vertical scroll??? why???) I want see image in orginal size. Image must loading when app start.

Answer (score 0):

You set the size of the scene, but not the view. The view is like a window into the scene, so if it's smaller, then you'll need to scroll to see the other parts of the scene. If the view and the scene match in size, no scrolling will be required.

Therefore, set the scene and view to a size larger than the pixmap to ensure you won't need to scroll to see the pixmap and the view to the same size as the scene to remove scrolling completely.

Answer (score 0):

```
ui->graphicsView->fitInView();
```

if you put your scene or image or whatever in the brackets it should be fit to view size :)